# Synchronize 2 posix threads

Tags: synchronization, thread-safety, pthreads

I have 2 threads and both of them are deleting memory at the end nedded by both. My problem is that maybe it can happen that a thread start and finish before the other one starts and so it deletes the memory nedded by the other thread. How can I synchronize them so that this can't happend.
As a design my threads look like this:

```
void* thread1(void* arg)   
{
   lock(&mutex);
   counter++;
   unlock(&mutex);

   // more code here

   lock(&mutex);
   counter--;
   if(counter == 0)
   {  
      delete a;
      delete b;
    }
    unlock(&mutex);
}
```

The other thread looks the same, but this isn't unoff to stop thread1 to finish before thread2 starts.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you just do:

```
void *thread1(void* arg)
{
   // your code

   lock(&mutex);
   counter++;
   if (counter == 2) {
      // whatever
   }
   unlock(&mutex);
}
```

assuming counter is initialized to 0 before either thread starts, of course.

Comment: so what if the first thread starts and ends before the second thread starts?

Comment: then `counter == 1` when the second thread starts until it takes the mutex. When thread2 gets the mutex, `counter++` raises it to 2, and thread2 can proceed with the cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

Good use of the mutex here, BTW.

You could add another counter, protected by the same mutex, and only do the increment on it.  Then in the exit code you could check it to confirm that all the threads got to start.

i.e. change it to "if (counter == 0 && started == 2)".

Since you are protecting counter & started access with a mutex, if 1 & 2 both start before either finishes, the first to finish will see started = 2 and counter = 1.  The other will see started = 2 and counter = 0 and delete the resources.

If a thread runs to completion before the other starts, it will see started = 1 and counter = 0.  Then the other thread will see started = 2 and counter = 0 and clean up.

Comment: thanks for replying, i just test to see if counter == 2, less code :)

Comment: Your code guarantees that the resources are created before either thread starts, yes?  In that case doing the counter == 2 should work.